# Google API: YouTube video uplaod error = 403

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting following error for uploading the video to youtube,

> YouTube-API-Demo[654:60b] Video Upload failed : Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled
>   for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction
>   configured on your API key and the request does not match these
>   restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your
>   configuration.)" UserInfo=0x16e922e0 {error=Access Not Configured. The
>   API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or
>   per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request
>   does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers
>   Console to update your configuration.,
>   GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x16daee10: {message:"Access Not
>   Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a
>   per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the
>   request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google
>   Developers Console to update your configuration." code:403 data:[1]},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Access Not Configured. The API is not
>   enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer
>   restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match
>   these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update
>   your configuration.)}

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the Youtube Data API for the App that you are using?
https://console.developers.google.com/project

You see a list of projects there and you have to active the APIs per project.

[image]

Otherwise there might be IP restrictions. You can restrict your App Token to only allow access for specific IPS. The default is "allow all IPs". There is a "Access" Tab somewhere.

Comment: how to activate it? click on specific project. Next what should I do?